# K&R Quicksort function argument

Tags: c, function, arguments

I was reading K&R function of quicksort algorithm however I didn't understand why we should have in its argument the int left and int right? Can we have only the int var [] argument?

You can find in the below the related code:

```
void qsort(int v[], int left, int right)
{
    int i, last;
    void swap(int v[], int i, int j);

    if (left >= right) /* do nothing if array contains */
        return;        /* fewer than two elements; left and right are indeces */

    swap(v, left, (left + right)/2); /* move partition elem to v[O]*/

    last = left;

    for (i = left+1; i <= right; i++) /* partition */
        if (v[i] < v[left])
            swap(v, ++last, i);

    swap(v, left, last); /* restore partition elem */
    qsort(v, left, last-1);
    qsort(v, last+1, right);
}

void swap (int v[], int i, int j)
{
    int temp;

    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please show the exact code you are referring to. You can't expect everyone to have that book at hand.

Comment: When you pass an array to a function, what gets passed is effectively a pointer (to the first element of the array). Pointers do not have information about number of elements in the (underlying) array, so you need to pass that too.

Comment: @kaylum yes you are right. I will share it shortly

Comment: @pmg but in that case we don't need the int left since int left will be always equal to V[0]

Comment: Sometimes you want to "work with" elements `12` thru `17` (`6` elements). You can do that as originally: `qsort(arr, 12, 17)` or assuming `0` for the start and using `6` for the length, as you propose, with `qsort(arr + 12, 6)`

Comment: @pmg aha ok now I understand. Thank you so much